# Table comment length in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

According to MySQL manual, table comments are limited to 60 characters. I'm designing the schema in MySQL Workbench, which does not enforce this limit, so I end up with writing more than 60 symbols quite often, and this causes the SQL script to fail. To tell the truth I would be quite happy with table comments being internal to my schema (i.e. not exported to the actual database), but Workbench doesn't allow this either. Hence my question: is there a way to increase maximum length of table comment in MySQL to 255?

Comment: This question is high on Google, so... The limit for MySQL 5.1 is 255. Quote: "A comment for a column can be specified with the COMMENT option, up to 255 characters long. The comment is displayed by the SHOW CREATE TABLE and SHOW FULL COLUMNS statements.".

Comment: Never mind. I just noticed this is about a table comment which is still limited to 60...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14502814/1725096

Comment: A comment for a column can be specified with the COMMENT option, up to 1024 characters long (255 characters before MySQL 5.5.3). The comment is displayed by the SHOW CREATE TABLE and SHOW FULL COLUMNS statements.

Comment: [MySQL 5.1 `CREATE TABLE` reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.1/sql-syntax.html#create-table): • Tables up to 60 characters. •  Columns up to 255 characters. || [MySQL 5.5 `CREATE TABLE` reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html): •  Tables up to 2048 characters (60 characters before MySQL 5.5.3). • Columns up to 1024 characters (255 characters before MySQL 5.5.3).

Answer (score 3):

According to [this bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34507), Workbench was fixed in 5.0.18 to not allow comments over 60 characters.

I'm pretty sure there's no way to increase the limit, but if you turn off strict mode (even temporarily while you import) then it should truncate it with a warning instead of throwing an error.

Comment: No, this is not correct, I have 5.0.28 and the length is still not enforced. In theory I don't complain, it is convenient to have long table annotations, but in practice it breaks my SQL scripts :(

Answer (score 3):

I came here from google - There is no way (besides the patch), but the comment lengths have been significantly increased, as I summed up here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14502814/857958

Comment: this is now outdated, see @blueimpb

Answer (score 3):

I came here from Google. This 60-character limit has been defunct for a *long* time http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html

> `COMMENT`
>
> A comment for the table, up to 2048 characters long (60 characters before MySQL 5.5.3).

Comment: also worth pointing out: `A comment for a column can be specified with the COMMENT option, up to 1024 characters long (255 characters before MySQL 5.5.3). The comment is displayed by the SHOW CREATE TABLE and SHOW FULL COLUMNS statements.`

Answer (score 0):

Patch to enable longer comments in MySQL available here, [link text](http://lists.mysql.com/commits/57746)

Comment: Patching the core database engine sounds like a dangerous way to work around a MySQL Workbench bug. It would be good if this patch was properly reviewed and added to MySQL, though.

Answer (score 0):

It is the first flaw i found in MySQL Workbench. I never used table comments before, but I do like them. Why use embrace (or prepend) the comments using hash tags in the generated SQL script? Won't fail them.