# How to increase mysql table comments length?

Tags: mysql, comments, ddl

Seems like max table comments length in mysql is only 60 characters.

I'm developing an aplicacion in php symfony, which automatically generates sql ddl sentences, and in many cases those comments are far beyond 60 characters.

Is there some way to increase that limit?

thanks a lot

Comment: I don't have a way to testing this right now. But table comments are stored in the "mysql" database in "tables" table. You may be try changing the size of the field it is stored in, or even manually entering more data into that field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know, it is impossible to make it by mysql standard means.

[Table comment length in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391323/table-comment-length-in-mysql)