# mysql: documentation for table attributes

Tags: mysql, documentation

Is there a way to attach documentation / comments to tables and attributes in mysql?

It's so natural to be able to document db attributes as you're documenting class properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can [add comments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html) to columns in MySQL:

```
alter table pancakes change house house int comment 'where is?'
```

And then you can view them with [`show full columns`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-columns.html):

> The FULL keyword causes the output to include the column collation and comments, as well as the privileges you have for each column.

Comments are [fairly spacious now](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html), they used to be [pretty small](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391323/table-comment-length-in-mysql):

> A comment for a column can be specified with the COMMENT option, up to 1024 characters long.

Comment: @Andrew: Sorry, I'm not familiar with phpMyAdmin.